# Count number of comments including specific word. Ruby on Rails 7.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, count, size

I want to count the number of comments that include a specific word. I am trying to do something like this:

```
<%= @post.comments.include?(reply: 'WORD').size %>
```

It does not work, and I also want to make it independent on word scaling, meaning it can be Word, WORD, or word. All three options should be counted.

I try something like this, it does not work:

```
<%= @post.comments.include?(reply: 'WORD').upcase.strip.size %>
```

And then I would like to show number of words left, meaning
(number provided - number of comments including word count).

Comment: Does the ILIKE operator work for you (`@post.comments.where('reply ILIKE ?', '%word%').count`)? What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: pls explain your last question... are you looking for the number of comments that *do not* include WORD (or word or Word)?

Comment: ILIKE works well. I have updated the question. Thank you big time!

Comment: Glad you sorted this out. Can you please post your answer as an answer? That way StackOverflow's filters know the question has been sorted out.

Answer (score 0):

This formula works for me:

(@post.comments.where('reply ILIKE ?', '%word%').count)?